# Print records using substr() function in php

Tags: php

Print records using substr() function in php.
Am trying to print january 22 from the record below. any help

```
 $rec= 'Thursday, January 22, 2015, 5:48 pm';

$get_january_22 = substr(strrchr($rec, ","), 3);
echo $get_january_22;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$rec   = 'Thursday, January 22, 2015, 5:48 pm';
$parts = explode(',', $res);

echo trim($parts[1]);
```

Comment: it works perfect.  Assuming i have  $rec   = '1234556789A'; and I want discard A and print only number what could be the solution.  Thanks